# Can't run more than 3 gearman workers on same server

Tags: php, web-worker, gearman

When i run gearman upto three workers on single server is working fine but when i start the 4th one php code is working fine but can't detect the new worker and also not clearing the job queue.

```
protected function createWorker()
{
    $this->worker = new \GearmanWorker();
    $config = $this->app->config->job_remote;
    $this->worker->addServer($config['host'], $config['port']);
    return $this->worker;
}
public function listen($eventType, $callback)
{
    if (!($this->worker instanceof \GearmanWorker)){
        $this->worker = $this->createWorker();
    }
    $this->worker->addFunction($eventType, $callback);
    return $this->worker;
}

public function doWork($worker)
{
    if (!($worker instanceof \GearmanWorker)){
        $worker = $this->createWorker();
    }
    $this->worker = $worker;
    while (1) {
        $this->worker->work();
        $this->app->log->debug($this->worker->returnCode());
        if ($this->worker->returnCode() != \GEARMAN_SUCCESS) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

First I am calling 'listen' method and then 'doWork' method

Client Side Code:

```
    protected function createClient()
    {
        $this->client = new \GearmanClient();
        $config = $this->app->config->job_remote;
        $this->client->addServer($config['host'], $config['port']);
        return $this->client;
    }

    public function addTask($eventType, array $params)
    {
    if (!($this->client instanceof \GearmanClient)){
        $this->client = $this->createClient();
    }
    // add single task in queue
    $this->client->addTaskBackground($eventType, serialize($params));
    // Run task
    $this->client->runTasks();
    }
```

Comment: Where is your code .. what did you tried

Comment: I have added the code now check

Comment: Where is your client code ??? from where you assigning job.

Comment: Dude upto 3 workers everything is working fine.

Comment: I have using GearmanManager and working currently on that project and i can get working up-to 50 workers. Even i tried 100 workers and it was working fine except it hangs my computer..

Comment: When i am run the 4th worker from cli php code is working but can't fetch the queue and also not shown in gearman monitor.

Comment: Can you share the code how will you run 50 or 100 workers

Comment: How many cores are on your server?  Check your load average, you may have simply run out of resources depending on what kind of processing you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Using GearmanManager  You can run upto any no. of workers untill it slows down your computer  and uses 100% cpu and 100% memory.

Gearman.ini

```
[GearmanManager]
worker_dir=./workers
count=50
dedicated_count=1
max_worker_lifetime=3600
auto_update=1
log_file=./logs/WebAnalyzerWorker.log
max_runs_per_worker=3
timeout=600
```

Run Gearman worker

```
./vendor/brianlmoon/gearmanmanager/pecl-manager.php -c ./gearman.ini -vvvvv
```

Worker CLass

```
<?php

include dirname(__DIR__)."/vendor/autoload.php";

use Services\Log;
use Services\ServiceInitialization;
use Lib\Technology\FindWhoisRecords;
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

class DomainDetailFetchJob{

    public function beforeRun()
    {
        ServiceInitialization::loadConfig();
        ServiceInitialization::loadDatabaseConfiguration();
    }

    public function run($job, &$log)
    {
        $log[] = "Starting whois job";
        $collection = "whois";
        $this->beforeRun();
        ServiceInitialization::$config->all();        
        $workload = $job->workload();
        //workload
        $whois = new FindWhoisRecords($workload);
        if($whois->whois_result["err_code"]==0) {
            $log[] = "Whois Info fetch successful";
            //success save the details
            $whois->whois_result["result"]["workload"] = $workload;
            Capsule::table($collection)->where("workload", $workload)->update($whois->whois_result["result"], ['upsert' => true]);

        }
        else {
            $log[] = "Whois Info fetch failed";
            $logger = new Log();
            $logger->write($whois->whois_result["err_msg"], "error", "Whois Record Job");
            unset($logger);
        }
    }

}
```

Gearman Client

```
$client = new GearmanClient();
$client->addServer();
$client->doBackground("DomainDetailFetchJob", $url);
```